# multi level dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a multi level dictionary from a file like this:

```
node1     :
 key1 : value1
node2          : 
 key2              :               value2
 key3              :               value3
 key4              :               value4
node3              : 
 key2              :               
  interkey2        :               value
node4          : 
 key2              :               
  interkey2        :               
   moreinterkey    :               value5
  interkey3        :               
   moreinterkey    :               value5
```

and I want that it keeps in memory to acces as:

```
>>> variable["node1"]["key2"]["interkey2"]
value2
```

any idea of which is the best way? I'm iterating line by line but I don't really know how to set the dict value depending of the level of each value

Thanks,

As seems my question is not really understand, I edit to put what I want to do, but I don't know how to make it more pythonic:

```
result = {}
level_keys = []
for line in input_text:
    actual_indent = len(line) - len(line.lstrip(' '))
    splitted_string = line.split(':')
    level_keys = level_keys[:actual_indent]
    level_keys[actual_indent] = splitted_string[0]
    if actual_indent == 0:
        result[level_keys[0]] = splitted_string[1]
    elif actual_indent == 1:
        result[level_keys[0]][level_keys[1]] = splitted_string[1]
    elif actual_indent == 2:
        result[level_keys[0]][level_keys[1]][level_keys[2]] = splitted_string[1]
    elif actual_indent == 3:
        result[level_keys[0]][level_keys[1]][level_keys[2]][level_keys[3]] = splitted_string[1]
return result
```

I hope now is more clear my question, sorry for the first attempt

Comment: What does your data input look like? Are you having trouble creating the dictionary or accessing it? You seem to already have a good idea as to how you want to store it by simply using a key/value pair with the value as a dict itself.

Comment: Are the different levels marked by the number of proceeding whitespaces? You just have to count the indentation level, and remember the last added keys.

Comment: @iChar the levels are variable, then I want to have a dictionary that can have pairs key/value and any of this keys can be (or not) a dictionary with pairs key/value and any of this keys can be (or not) a dictionary... I can limit the level to 4 or 5

Comment: @fodma1 this is exactly what I'm trying to do, I am counting the indentation level, and I know how to save the last added keys, but how can add the new pair/key if I only know the level in runtime, I don't know how to set the profundity of assignement in runtime...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a custom file format, could you use YAML file format and use a well-known parsing library. For example, the example in landing page of the [PyYAML Documentation](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) looks quite similar to yours.

The first example - setup:

```
import yaml
document = """
  a: 1
  b:
    c: 3
    d: 4
"""
print yaml.dump(yaml.load(document))
```

The first example - output:

```
a: 1
b: {c: 3, d: 4}
```

Comment: I can't change the file format, really is not a file, is a console output program I want to input and use